# Create an API from EDA or ML outcome?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pandas

I have the following sample dataset (the actual dataset is over 10 million records)

```
     Passenger    Trip
0       Mark     London
1       Mike     Girona
2    Michael      Paris
3        Max     Sydney
4     Martin  Amsterdam
5     Martin  Barcelona
6     Martin  Barcelona
7       Mark     London
8       Mark      Paris
9     Martin   New york
10       Max     Sydney
11       Max      Paris
12       Max     Sydney
...
...
...
```

And I wanted to get the destination frequently travelled by a passenger !

I was playing around in Jupyter and got the expected data with the following approach

```
series_px = df_px_dest.groupby('Passenger')['Trip'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(1))

df_px = series_px.to_frame() 

df_px.index = df_px.index.set_names(['UName', 'DEST'])

df_px.reset_index(inplace=True) 

def getNextPossibleDestByUser(pxname,df=df_px): 
    return df.query('UName==@pxname')['DEST'].to_string(index=False)
```

While the response is fine. I have few doubts now

1) What's the best way to expose the method (say in this case getNextPossibleDestByUser) as a API (pass customer name as input and get the destination as output) ?

2) Whenever the API is being called , does that mean all the 10 million records gets processed each time ? Are there anyway to optimise that ?

3) Rather than dataframe (pandas) query approach can I consider some ml models or utility functions from say scikit to solve the same problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the best way to expose the method (say in this case getNextPossibleDestByUser) as a API (pass customer name as input and get the destination as output) ?

Use [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). Pretty [easy to build an API](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-a-web-application-using-flask-and-deploy-it-to-the-cloud-3551c985e492).

> Whenever the API is being called , does that mean all the 10 million records gets processed each time ? Are there anyway to optimise that ?

It depends on the exact application but for you case you can take the passenger as an input from the call to your [API as POST body](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-post-requests-using-python/) or in the arguments and only iterate over the subset of data for that passenger.

> Rather than dataframe (pandas) query approach can I consider some ml models or utility functions from say scikit to solve the same problem ?

If the problem is -- as you illustrated -- simple frequency calculations then better to stick to pandas, in my opinion. If your problem is solved by the simple approach it would not make sense to go for a complicated approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try
Djangorestframework
example : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#example

In django views you have to write all code and can define parameters there.